# How can I convert an integer to a string in a document nested in an array in Pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I have a document, nested in an array in mongoDB. One of the document elements is an integer but I need to convert it to be a string. I have tried to use many different approaches to this, using both the `update_one()` and `update_many()` functions. I have also tried to use `$toString`, `$set` and `$convert` in different ways and I even found a post that tried to use the `aggregate()` function. None of my attempts seem to yield any results. Some of these attempts produce errors but for the most part it just seems like it's working until I check the data and nothing has changed.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("62d7e96b3348d2ed4d3f6c37"),
    "index": 2394,
    "hashDec": "17795682514039271424",
    "hashHex": "0xf6f6f6f600f0f000",
    "postList": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1659646945.456782,
        "uploadTime": 1659646903.0,
        "author": "Osinttechnical",
        "id": 1555297956483305472,
        "platform": "twitter",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "platform": "twitter",
        "id": 1567987802234851328,
        "author": "UAWeapons",
        "text": "#Ukraine: A Russian Ural-4320 transport truck had a a slight accident and was abandoned in #Kharkiv Oblast.",
        "timestamp": 1662672491.5861459,
        "uploadTime": 1662672398.0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here's what would seem most logical to me:

```py
self.allDocs = list(self.video.find({}).sort("index"))

        for index, doc in enumerate(self.allDocs):

            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Updating doc: {doc['index']}")

            for post in doc["postList"]:

                if isinstance(post["id"], int):

                    print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Updating post: {post}")
                    self.video.update_one({"index": doc["index"],
                        "postList.$[].id": post["id"]},
                        {"$set": {"postList.$[].id": str(post["id"])}},
                        upsert=False)
```

Does anyone know how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use `update_many` with the [aggregation pipeline update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) feature, this allows you to execute a single update to achieve this without the overhead of reading all documents into memory like you're doing.

It will look like so:

```
self.video.update_many({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "postList": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$postList",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "id": {
                  "$toString": {
                    "$toLong": "$$this.id"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZSH6E1Ddsqt)